# Why does Settings.System.put/get methods require a ContentResolver?

Tags: android

From my understanding, you get a ContentResolver from a Context.  Where..if you want to change the System's settings, you have to write to "System's Context", right?.

What I'm asking is..why does the put/get methods require a ContentResolver, and where do you get it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ContentResolver is used to interact with a ContentProvider which ultimately reads and writes to a database. Those system settings are likely backed by a DB. That is why you need a ContentResolver so you can write to the Settings DB. Also, the System does not have a "context" in the same way that an Application or an Activity would.

Comment: Which ContentProvider's ContentResolver I need to pass in to Settings.System.put?  I could..just getContentResolver() from my Activity or Service, but that doesn't really make sense to me.  I'm writing to the System's settings, why do I need to pass my own ContentResolver to it?

Comment: ContentResolver is your local API for...  resolving content: URIs.  The settings are behind a content: URI.  Your ContentResolver can figure out how to find them.  Just use it.